# AJAX runs error callback on 403 when it has my data?

Tags: php, ajax, wamp

This is a major revision of an earlier question because I feel I misunderstood the nature of my problem. My GET request sent via AJAX to a standalone PHP script on my own WAMP server is landing me 403 Forbidden... but I get the output I want. Let me explain:

I have...

1. Set `Full Control` permissions all across the board. All of them.
2. I used both relative and absolute paths, along with complete URLS using both 127.0.0.1 and localhost.
3. The standalone has `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
4. Restarted Apache with redundant `<Directory ...>` and `Allow from all` directives in .htaccess and httpd.conf.
5. Went through 8 pages of [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=403+forbidden+causes)
6. Read everything I could find on StackOverflow.
7. Sacrificed a goat and threw a virgin into a volcano.

I can access the file directly by typing its address in the browser and see the output I want. When I run this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'lib/GetNextTags.php',
  data: {
    context_code : context_code
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //...
    },
    error: function( event, jqxhr, ajaxSettings, thrownError ) {
        alert(event.responseText);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

The success callback is not called, but the error callback is. The event object passed as an argument contains the output I've been trying to get in `event.responseText`. `event.readyState` is 4. I used `json_encode()` and encoded everything as UTF-8, so I don't think jQuery had an issue with decoding.

So... Why the 403? Why the error callback?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the AJAX url directly in the browser?

Comment: I have accessed the script directly. I get output without a 403 then. The error only occurs through a script call. Post updated with this info.

Comment: It could be permission issue. You can use [chmod +x file.php] to set proper execute permission.

Comment: I'm on WAMP, so `chmod` is out. I set 'Full Control' permissions through properties dialogs. Anything else I could try with permissions? (There is no .htaccess in the standalone's folder. Going to try using one)

Comment: Try using localhost if you are using 127.0.0.1 in AJAX url or vice versa

Comment: After adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, the script seems to run. However, success callback still does not run. The jqXHR passed in an `.ajaxError()` callback I just made reports `200 OK`. Session info also no longer updating. So, its either forbidden and partially run or not forbidden and not run at all? I'm going to go play in traffic, excuse me.